# Node.js drive api, setting emailMessage when creating a permission does not send email

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

Using drive api v3 with Node.js `googleapis` v61.0.0 client.  When creating a permission, any time I set the param 'emailMessage' to anything other an empty string (or not specifying it at all also works), I do not receive the notification email at all.  Response comes back as 200, and permissions get set properly, however, no email is sent. I can also see from the request it's sent properly and server has it properly sent back in the params object.

```
const result = await this.drive.permissions.create({
                emailMessage: 'test test',
                sendNotificationEmail: true,
                supportsAllDrives: true,
                resource: permission,
                fileId,
                fields: 'id'
            });
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your situation, `emailMessage: 'test test',` is used, the email is not sent even when `sendNotificationEmail: true,` is used. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in that case, when the same email addresses are used, the issue can be replicated? By the way, the email addresses is email of Google? If it's not, when you tested your script for Google email, what result will you obtain? And can you show the value of `permission`? Because, in my environment, your script works.

Comment: When using async/await I strongly recommend you to use **try-catch** block so we can see if there's a silent error being thrown despite the permissions created. Can you confirm there's not an error you are not "catching"?

Comment: @tanaike the email goes to a gmail account internal company email domain, it's mine that i'm testing it with. permissions look like `{type: 'uesr', role: 'writer', emailAddress: 'myemail@company.com' }`

@jose-vasquez I do have it in a try catch block no exception is thrown and result is a 200 response

Comment: Here is a sample of the response I get from the api call:
`
{
 status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  request: {
    responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileid-omitted>/permissions?emailMessage=test%20test&sendNotificationEmail=true&supportsAllDrives=true&fields=id'
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

### This error might be caused by the scope

Despite the reflected changes without using the `sendNotificationEmail` parameter. If you are using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` try using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope. This is an error in the documentation.

### Reference

[Google Drive API v3 > Permissions > Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#auth)

[Google API NodeJS Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/drive/v3.ts#L6383)